# Extensions, PluginKit and craziness on macOS

Tags: macos, plugins

Our macOS application has an extension.

As soon as an application with extension is launched for a first time, PluginKit registers it and when it's deleted then plugin is unregistred.

PluginKit also have some algorithm how to choose which plugin to load (I assume it's just latest version).

However, I stumbled on so many problems:

- I run application from XCode and for some reason plugin got unregistered
- I delete an app and PluginKit didn't remove registration
- I saw a registration magically disappear for one of beta users

I am puzzled. This whole plugin behaves quite unreliably.

I found a way to trooubleshoot and fix it:

```
pluginkit -v -m -D -i <bundleid>
pluginkit -a <path>
pluginkit -r <path>
```

Do you see such problems? How do you deal with these issues? Do you have some code (programmatically try to clean up pluginkit DB?)

Comment: Hi Victor, can you please share the way to register the extension using PluginKit?

Comment: I have all the same problems, yeah.

Comment: For future readers, this is still an issue on mac OS 14.